# Can someone explain what is going on here?

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-collections

Scala beginner, here. I'm pretty confused by this entire expression, to be honest. I vaguely understand what this is supposed to do, but what are the ~s doing?

```
val simple = {
   get[String]("user.email") ~
   get[String]("user.name") ~
   get[String]("user.password") map {
     case email~name~password => User(email, name, password)
   }
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/scala/zentasks/app/models/User.scala) the github source if you're curious or need more info.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the method `RowParser.~` combines two separate RowParsers for separate columns, giving result RowParser[anorm.~[Col1Type, Col2Type]]. Here's the processing details:

1. Singleton `object` `anorm.SqlParser` has all members imported.
2. It has a method `get[T]`:

   ```
   def get[T](columnName: String)(implicit extractor: Column[T]): RowParser[T]
   ```

   - when called, generic param `T` is instantiated as `String`
   - input param `columnName` is populated as `"user.email"`, etc
   - input param `extractor` is `implicit`.  It's not provided in calls. So, the compiler picks up an implicit value using the type signature matching within the `Column` singleton object.  It finds method `rowToString: Column[String]`.
   - output params `RowParser[T]` is instantiated `RowParser[String]`
3. `anorm.RowParser[String]` has method "`~`" called.  It's signature is:

   ```
   def ~[B](p: RowParser[B]): RowParser[~[String, B]]
   ```
4. But what is the input (parameter p) for "`~`"?  It's on the next line: `get[String]("user.name") ~`.
5. Because of this "chaining" of method calls, the method call order is actually bottom-up:

   - first

     ```
     get[String]("user.password") map {
       case email~name~password => User(email, name, password)
     ```

     which returns type `RowParser[String]`
   - which is passed into

     ```
     get[String]("user.name") ~
     ```

     which returns type `RowParser[~[String, String]]`.  Here, this uses a different "~" - the *type* `anorm.~[A,B]` which is defined as a case class:

     ```
     case class ~[+A, +B](_1: A, _2: B) extends Product with Serializable
     ```

     representing the result of conjoining two parsed columns in the row.
   - This RowParser is passed into:

     ```
     get[String]("user.email") ~
     ```

     which returns type `RowParser[~[String, RowParser[~[String, String]]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The '~' is a parser combinator that operates on a row. It validates the existence of user.emal, user.name, user.password, the result of which (if successful) is a ~[A, B, C] which can be mapped. In this case, if all 3 exist, a new User object is created and returned.